# How can I create a #21 orange filter in PS 2022?

Tags: photoshop, digital

I would like to set up a standard #21 orange filter in PS 2022's black & white widget. It's inscrutably not included in the list, though it's a popular and useful B&W filter. I've found the Pantone RBG values (#fe5000) but the widget also wants CMY values, which I've been unable to find. Is there a method to calculate?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://colormine.org/convert/rgb-to-cmy

Comment: What 'widget'? If you put RGB values in the colour-picker, it automatically fills the CMYK & all the others… https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKRlX.png